# Firestore reducer in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I've got the following piece of code for my reducers:

```
import { Reducer, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import { firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { firestoreReducer } from 'redux-firestore';

const reducers: Reducer<ApplicationState> = combineReducers<ApplicationState>({
  firebase: firebaseReducer,
  firestore: firestoreReducer,
  router: routerReducer
});

export { reducers };
```

I was pretty much following tutorial that could be found [here](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/master/docs/firestore.md)

However `firestore` reducer complains with the following message:

```
Argument of type '{ firebase: typeof firebaseReducer; firestore: typeof firestoreReducer; router: Reducer<RouterSta...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducersMapObject'.
  Property 'firestore' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'typeof firestoreReducer' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<any>'.
      Type 'typeof firestoreReducer' provides no match for the signature '(state: any, action: AnyAction): any'.
```

What could be the issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like TS is looking for a `Reducer` in the spot that `firebaseReducer` is, but found something else. To see what that 'something else' is, I went to see the types, [found this](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore/blob/40489248992206638a7b0d07bb6b1c23c8bdb72c/index.d.ts#L99), and... become promptly confused. It looks like the types are more than just *broken*, they may as well not even be there. Casting it manually may be your best bet here.

```
const reducers: Reducer<ApplicationState> = combineReducers<ApplicationState>({
  firebase: firebaseReducer,
  firestore: firestoreReducer as Reducer<ApplicationState>,
  router: routerReducer
});
```

[I'd also consider opening up an issue or PR for this.](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore/issues) It's kind of baffling no one's run into this before.

Comment: Yep, I also checked types and came here. Casting as `Reducer<ApplicationState>` helps, but I'll open an issue anyway.